# How to get value from RadioButtonList using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, radiobuttonlist

I need to find out what is the selected value of RadioButtonList:

```
<div class="editor-field radio-button-list">
   <%= Html.RadioButtonListForEnum("Type", Model.Type)%>
</div>
```

I tried to use: `$("#Type").find(":checked").val()` but all I get is "undefined"... Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the rendered HTML instead of whatever code that is?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm not sure the id of Type is coming out how you think it is.  Or maybe Type is a duplicate Id.  In any event, I think this is what you want

```
$(".editor-field.radio-button-list").find(":checked").val()
```

Answer (score 5):

It's working for server side control:

```
$("#<%=ControlID.ClientID%>").find(":checked").val();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".editor-field.radio-button-list:checked").val()
```

Answer (score 0):

`var val = $('#<%= ControlID.ClientID %> input:checked').val();`